# Turn off notification when tp / sl

Tags: pine-script

I have problem with my strategy and trading bot. First of all I have bot which is working with Supertrend strategy. The notification over there is `{"symbol": "{{ticker}}", "side": "{{strategy.order.action}}"}`.

Now I Have another strategy but this strategy have tp/sl. When I used `{"symbol": "{{ticker}}", "side": "{{strategy.order.action}}"}` in every tp/sl its notification about it amd trading bot want to open position in different direction. I cannot add `{{strategy.order.comment}}` because I will need to change all MySQL base and other thinkg.

Could you help me how I can turn off notification in my new strategy?

```
// Close Deal on SL, TP or TTP
// ----------------------------------
if math.abs(strategy.position_size) > 0
take_profit_factor = IS_LONG ? 1 + take_profit : 1 - take_profit
stop_loss_factor = IS_LONG ? 1 - stop_loss : 1 + stop_loss
ttp_factor = IS_LONG ? 1 - ttp : 1 + ttp
stop_level := bo_level * stop_loss_factor
if take_profit_type == '% from total volume'
    take_profit_level := strategy.position_avg_price * take_profit_factor
    take_profit_level
else
    take_profit_level := bo_level * take_profit_factor
    take_profit_level

// Stop Loss
stop_loss_on_bar := false
if stop_loss > max_dev and not ttp_active
    if IS_LONG and low < stop_level
        stop_loss_counter += 1
        strategy.exit(id='x', stop=stop_level, comment='SL')
        stop_loss_on_bar := true
        stop_loss_on_bar
    else if not IS_LONG and high > stop_level
        stop_loss_counter += 1
        strategy.exit(id='x', stop=stop_level, comment='SL')
        stop_loss_on_bar := true
        stop_loss_on_bar
if not stop_loss_on_bar
    if ttp == 0.0
        // Simple take profit
        strategy.exit(id='x', limit=take_profit_level, comment='TP')
    else
        // Trailing take profit
        if IS_LONG and high >= take_profit_level
            ttp_extremum := math.max(high, ttp_extremum)
            ttp_active := true
            ttp_active
        if not IS_LONG and low <= take_profit_level
            ttp_extremum := math.min(low, ttp_extremum)
            ttp_active := true
            ttp_active
        if ttp_active
            ttp_level := ttp_extremum * ttp_factor
            strategy.exit(id='x', stop=ttp_level, comment='TTP')

  // Cleanup
  if ta.crossunder(strategy.opentrades, 0.5)
  strategy.close_all()
  strategy.cancel_all()
```